# Deducing a user-defined-value template argument (C++2a, P0732R2)

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to get the value of a template parameter of a user-defined class deduced (http://wg21.link/p0732r2), using GCC 9.1 with -std=c++2a.

```
struct user_type {
   int a;
   constexpr user_type( int a ): a( a ){}
};

template< user_type u > struct value {};

template< user_type u > void f( value< u > arg ){}  

void g(){
  f( value< user_type( 0 ) >() ); // error here
}
```

compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/6v_p_R

I get the error:

```
source>:8:30: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:11:33: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'u'
   11 |    f( value< user_type( 0 ) >() );
```

Am I doing something wrong? I had expected such a value to be deductible.

As suggested by Nikita I added == and != operators to user-type, but that made no difference.

```
struct user_type {
   int a;
   constexpr user_type( int a ): a( a ){}
   constexpr bool operator==( const user_type & arg ) const {
      return a == arg.a;
   }
   constexpr bool operator!=( const user_type & arg ) const {
      return a != arg.a;
   }
};
```

Comment: There is no CTAD happening anywhere in your code. Given that this is a fairly basic use of user-defined value templates, this seems like a compiler bug.

Comment: The `user_type` does not have comparison operator that the paper seems to require from the type. It actually requires `operator<=>` that GCC currently does not support. There is also a mangling problem that the paper also notices and it is not clear how it was resolved if it even was.

Comment: There is *function* template argument deduction in the f( ... ) call: the compiler must deduce the value of u.

Comment: @Nikita the P0732R2 taks about classes that  "have a non-user-provided operator<=>". I think I fulfill that requirement ;)

Comment: @Wouter van Ooijen no, it says about equality, and `user_type` type is not    EqualityComparable. https://godbolt.org/z/3s_1aU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be ill-formed:

```
struct user_type {
   int a;
   constexpr user_type( int a ): a( a ){}
};

template< user_type u > struct value {};
```

In order to be a template non-type parameter, you need to satisfy [[temp.param]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4):

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - a literal type that has strong structural equality ([class.compare.default]),
> - [...]

Where strong structural equality requires, from [[class.compare.default]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.compare.default#3):

> A type C has strong structural equality if, given a glvalue x of type const C, either:
>
> - C is a non-class type and [...], or
> - C is a class type **with an == operator defined as defaulted in the definition of C**, x == x is well-formed when contextually converted to bool, all of C's base class subobjects and non-static data members have strong structural equality, and C has no mutable or volatile subobjects.

The key is that we need a defaulted `==` in the type... and we don't have one, so our type doesn't have strong structural equality, so it cannot be used as a template non-type parameter.

However,  gcc [doesn't let you](https://godbolt.org/z/l0R_Xy)  declare such an operator yet, so you can't fix the problem.

This is just an incomplete implementation of a new feature.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the revelant clause! "The key is that we have a defaulted == in the type. Not only do we not have a defaulted == but gcc doesn't even let you declare such an operator yet." - is there either a not missing, or a not that shouldn't be there?

Comment: Adding operator== did not solve the problem, so I think there are two bugs? 1) without operator== the user_type value should not be accepted as a template parameter, and 2) with the operator== the f( ... ) call should be allowed?

Comment: @Wouter Adding operator== doesn't solve the problem because, as I said, gcc doesn't let you do so yet. If it did, that would be the requirement to get even the declaration of the template to be valid.